# Как отключить Яндекс Дзен принципиально в браузере?

Tags: браузер, настройка

По запросу "отключить Яндекс.Дзен" в Интернете советы, которые не работают. Как навсегда отключить это?

Вместо "дзена" - раздражение. AdBlocker и подобные не могут с этим справиться. Техподдержка Яндекса в глухой обороне.

Гуано под названием Яндекс Дзен появляется где угодно. Меня статьи с ЯДа раздражают.

Я не против рекламы, но я против всякого гуано.

Comment: вы про оповещения?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, я про всю систему.

Comment: я не понимаю о чем речь ..., приложите скрин

Comment: что это за браузер?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, великий и ужасный FireФокс

Comment: @Adokenai нет. Это Яндекс Firefox со встроенным мусором от Яндекса.

Comment: У вас наверное стоит расширение Визуальные закладки от Яндекса, в его настройках можно отключить Дзен

Comment: @Vitaliy Antal нельзя

Comment: Справа внизу должен быть ссылка Настройки, в ней отключить последний пункт

Comment: @Vitaliy Antal раньше можно было. А теперь это гуано везде.

Comment: @Adokenai, а нельзя ли делать это на уровне таблиц роутинга? Т.е. по "черному списку" IP (не будут же они их постоянно менять)

Comment: @avp в этом месте поподробнее. Если что использую Windows 10

Comment: Ну, как это делать в винде, я точно не знаю. Поспрашивайте с соответствующей формулировкой, наверное спецы в администрировании сетки найдутся

Comment: @avp hosts в Win10 игнорируется

Comment: Там есть кнопка "Скрыть дзен", все. Я на всех браузерах его выключаю без проблем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть замечательные плагины для браузеров для блокировки Дзена (он очень отвлекает, это факт).

- Mozilla Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/block-yandex-zen/
- Google Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-yandex-zen/lkgpcmngelmpmiggaliejepmliicodfm

Comment: Возьмите пожалуйста на заметку, данный сайт не является ссылкообменником. Приведя ссылку как источник приведите хотя бы кратко её содержание, чтобы после её удаления/перемещения осталось хоть минимум информации.

Answer (score 1):

Качайте [нормальный Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/download/thanks/), а не версию со встроенным мусором от Яндекса.

Comment: Увы. Нет браузера с блокировкой этого гуано.